# Which login credentials are expected in Windows 10 RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, microsoft-account, remmina

I'm trying to set up Windows RDP to remote control a Microsoft Surface Book (Windows 10), being used as a home computer, from the internet. I'm getting a lot of confusing information on what login credentials are expected. I'm viewing using remmina on debian, so I have..

- Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my internet-facing IP address)
- User Name: ???
- Password: mymicrosoftpassword
- Domain: ???

My Microsoft account is named like John Smith, with just John in the corner as my first name. The account itself is toomanynames@gmail.com
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfpok.png). This is what I use to login on my browser.

but Microsoft automatically generated a microsoft email for me, outlook_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@outlook.com.

My computer is part of a WORKGROUP. Locally my notebook calls itself Johnny, and the actual user I'm trying to RDP to is toomany.

I've tried every combination I could but there's still an authentication error.

Comment: Get on the machine you want to login to and login. Run a cmd and type `whoami`. That would give you the login name you should be using. Depending on the tool the Domain would be the computer name as well. What is the actual error?

Comment: That returns johnny\toomany, which I'm fairly sure I tried along with some domain.

Comment: Actual error is SSL_read: error:14094419:SSL routines:SSL3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert access denied credssp_recv() error: -1
Authentication failure, check credentials.
If credentials are valid, the NTLMSSP implementation may be to blame.
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure